# Jquery ajax is not sending data

Tags: php, jquery

For some reason ajax is not sending data.

On the PHP I have this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    echo "submit";
} else {
    echo "not submit";
}
```

And I get not submit.
This is JS code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var length = $('#number').val();
        var small = $('#small').val();
        var big = $('#big').val();
        var number = $('#numero').val();
        var special = $('#special').val();
        var submit = 'submit';
        var url = 'public/php/codegenerator.php';
        var data = "length=" + length + "&small=" + small + "&big=" + big +
                   "&number=" + number + "&special=" + special + "&submit=" + submit;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function () {
                $('#code').load(url, function () {
                    $(this).fadeIn(1000)
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        //YOUR CODE

       var param = {
            length:length,
            small:small,
            big:big,
            number:number,
            special:special,
            submit:submit
        }

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: param,   

            //EDITED LINE     
            success: function (data) {
                $('#code').hide().html(data).fadeIn(1000);
            }               
        });       
        return false;
    });               
});
```

**// REVISED ANSWER**

// IN YOUR PHP FILE

```
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) { 
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>"submit"));
}
else {
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>"not submit"));
}
```

//IN YOUR JQUERY CODE

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: url,
    data: param, 
    dataType:'json';  

    //EDITED LINE     
    success: function (data) {
        // alert(data.result);
        $('#code').hide().html(data.result).fadeIn(1000);
    }               
});
```

Comment: why are you calling same url twice. first in outer ajax and second in inner ajax

Comment: It is duplicating original file (index.php) and not getting any data from the outside PHP file.

Comment: Yes, I did, and edited code is duplication original file. After submit is clicked it is duplicating hole page.

Comment: it seems that your php file is returning data with whole html. So i did some changes in answer to work with return type JSON. let me know what its returning.

Comment: It is working now. Response is submit. Now I need to work with JSON, and I not good with that :(.

Comment: you can check the POINT NO 2 with in this tutorial -   link http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Not submit, because it comes from the .load() call and not from .ajax - and in the load call you just load the URL without passing any POST data. So why you are running .load inside the success callback of .ajax with the same url?

Comment: I am trying to get data from that page (in this case echo result submit)

Comment: The correct code would be
success: function (data) {
$('#code').html(data);
}

Comment: It is duplicating original file (index.php) and not getting any data from the outside PHP file.